# Ubuntu thru Multipass (on Mac) cannot be accessed from RDP on Win

Tags: networking, ubuntu

Current config: Multipass Ubuntu 22.04 VM (Name: primary) on Mac 12.7 Able to shell and RDP into 'primary' from Mac easily.

XRDP installed and running on Ubuntu.
Constrained to only use MS RDP on Windows (can't change that).
However, Unable to RDP from Windows on same network.

Do I need to use a different IP to connect from Windows? I have read about IP redirection? Please suggest.

Tried connecting to RDP from Windows using the same IP i used on Mac (Host of VM) but it doesn't connect.

Edit: hostname -i gives 127.0.1.1 while assigned IP shows 192.168.64.2

I tried [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756713/remote-desktop-azure-linux-vm) and netplay settings brought the connection to Wired Connected from Wired Unmanaged. However, I still cannot ping the VM from the Windows or connect it thru RDP.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question as I do not have this setup. Two things to consider.  On all my Linux VMs on 2 machines hostname -i shows 127.0.0.1 so I do not think this is your issue.  Second:  to RDP from Windows on one machine to Linux on the second machine, the Linux VM must be on a Bridged Connection, not NAT.

Comment: Thank you @john Hi I tried this for bridging, not sure if it made a difference as I still cannot connect.  How do we know if I am currently bridged? does that assign a new IP? https://multipass.run/docs/bridged-network

Comment: Bridged Network assigns a router address to the machine .(NAT has its own internal DHCP server).   You can look at the IP of the Ubuntu machine and it should have a router address (like 192.168.1.xxx).

Comment: Also do not forget (small point) you must start xrdp each time you restart Linux.